# Variable scope problem accessing outer variable

Tags: php, variables, scope

I have a function with a big hierarchy:

```
function func(){
    $a= 0; // Here the variable is 0
    while(...){
        echo $a; // gives me always 0
        for(...){
            if(...){
                if(...){
                    $num = func3();
                    $a = $num; // this $a does not corrospond to $a in the beginning
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change the value of `$a` from the nested scopes?

Comment: Not to beat up on PHP, but seriously? Does that code not change the value of the `$a` declared within `func()`? If so, that's crazy. I'd really value an answer that explained *why* PHP does things like that. Seems really, really odd to me.

Comment: I think there is a difference between this sample code and your code, as this should definitely work.

Comment: either that or func3() simply always returns 0

Comment: Please post the real code as this code sets $a = func3() as many times as the while and for loops run (minus the if conditions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to PHP 5.3, PHP only has two scopes: global and local function scope.  PHP 5.3 introduced closures, which complicated the scope situation a bit, but it doesn't look like you're using them here.

Unlike many other C style programming languages, brackets/blocks do **not** invoke another level of scopre.  The `$a` you declare at the start of the function is the same `$a` that you're accessing later.  If the value you're getting in `$a` is unexpected, it's the missing code (...) that's changing its value, either through an assignment or because it's being passed by reference into some other function that's changing its value.

Answer (score 0):

you probably are using $a in a previous scope or func3() has set "global $a;" or maybe the if statements are never reached

Answer (score -1):

Global it.

```
global $a;

func() {
  $a = 0;
  while() {
    echo $a;
    for() {
      if() {
        if() {
          $a = func3();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Not complaining, just trying to understand better.

Comment: 1. Because using a global scope is almost never the right answer. 2. The problem isn't a scope problem, since PHP doesn't create a new scope when it encounters a {} block.